# How to crop an image to fit grid cell (for slider)?

Tags: html, css, grid, png

[screenshot of css grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mg4Qs.jpg)

I need a little help here, I need to make a slider, which is doing a comparison between 2 png images. I know how to make this for NON-transparrent pictures, but here I have 2 png cats width transparent bg.

Problem is that one cat should overlap another 1, but it looks impossible with 2 pngs.

I tried this code, but it doesn't work :(

```
kitties {
    display: grid;
    overflow: hidden;
    max-width: 592px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    grid-template-columns: 50% 1fr;
  }
.slider__fat-cat--range {
  .outline(red);
  grid-column: 1 / 2;
  grid-row: 1 / 2;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 2;
  object-fit: fill;
}
.slider__skinny-cat--range {
  .outline(rgb(0, 254, 59));
  justify-content: end;
  grid-column: 2 / 3;
  grid-row: 1 / 2;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

I tried to use css grid and position: absolute, but pasts of the 2nd png is always visible behind 1st

Comment: Could you please add all of your code :)

Comment: ```
<div class="slider__image-wrapper">
<img class="slider__fat-cat--range slider-image" src="../source/img/cat- fat_slider.png" alt="">  
<img class="slider__skinny-cat--range slider-image" src="../source/img/cat-skinny_slider.png" alt="">  
</div>  
```

 is it enough ? literally all code is 1000 rows :D

Comment: Sorry, couldn't handle line breaks :(

Comment: You want them to be positioned directly over each other??

Comment: Yep, and alter, after adding JS to the page, user will be able to compare 2 images like smooth before/after. Here's a reference <https://snipboard.io/12XCuM.jpg>